# Capacitors capacity in an RLC circuit that is in resonance

Tags: passive-networks, resonance, homework

[image]

So if its in resonance that means XL=XC right?

anyway thats how I started

I∠=Irms∠=7.07/sqrt2 ∠30° A

ω=10^3

Z1=R+jXL=1+1∠90°=sqrt2∠45°

Z2=-jXC=1∠-90°

Ztotal=(1/Z1+1/Z2)^-1=sqrt2∠-45°

U∠=I∠*Ztotal∠

U∠=7.07∠-15° V

I2∠=U∠/Z2=7.07∠75

UL∠=U∠, I2∠=I∠

UL=I/Cjω

C=I/ULjω=7.07∠75 / 7.07∠-15°j10^3=0.001F

Comment: So if your question is "So if its in resonance that means XL=XC right?" what are all the other characters and picture for?  =-D

Comment: Well I need to get capacitors capacity, and the circuit in the picture is in resonance, i(t) is given so I can get the voltage, the rest maybe to confuse people IDK we had to solve such a problem in school and thats how it looked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At resonance, XC = XL.
If the inductance is known, then XL = ωL.
The capacitive reactance is XC = 1 / ωC.
Hence C = 1 / (ω^2 * L).

Comment: but wont the Resistor on the inductor side change it from it being just XL=XC

Comment: Resistance doesn't affect the reactance. An ideal resistor doesn't have any reactive properties, so it would only directly affect the real power of a circuit. So when finding the capacitance at the resonant frequency, the value of the resistor doesn't matter.

Comment: R does not affect resonance condition XL=XC at resonance frequency, nor the frequency itself. It will affect how sharp the resonance is (Q-factor).